# Speeding Up DataFrame .mask() Iteration

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, conditional-statements

Is there a faster way to perform conditional calculations to certain DataFrame columns than using .mask()? My code shown below seems to work, but it can be slow when I use a large dataset.

```
def inversing(column):
    DF = pd.read_csv('DataFrame.csv')
    DF[column] = DF[column].mask(DF[column] !=0, 1/DF[column])

columns_to_inverse = ['a','b','c']
inverting(columns_to_inverse)
```

Comment: Can you please add an inline definition of DF?

Comment: Do my changes make sense? DF is just a data frame from a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this, but a straight forward one would be using a lambda:
`df[column].apply(lambda x: 1/x if x != 0 else x)`

Full code in jupyter notebook with timings:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-50, 50, 100))
%timeit df[0].mask(df[0] !=0, 1/df[0])
%timeit df[0].apply(lambda x: 1/x if x != 0 else x)
```

Which yields on my machine:

```
1.58 ms ± 6.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
324 µs ± 642 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This great! Thank you. This ran quite a bit faster on my machine than the previous method.